# How do I manipulate colors?

Tags: colors

In `sage`, I got a lot of bright blue colors that aren't readable.
I want to change them, but I don't know colors' source or from where they are coming.

*How can I change colors to my liking?*

Below you can find 2 screenshot of my terminal opened on `sage`.

[image: Terminal Screenshot 1]
I did use `setterm` to change foreground text, but the problem is that it is still bright blue in color?
[image: Terminal Screenshot 2]

Comment: @AndroidDev no I did use setterm, still the color remains bright blue, for the foreground text.